# local variable 'juveniles' referenced before assignment

Tags: function, variables, python-3.x, scope, return

```
 def menu():
    option = int(input("Please select an option: \n 1: Set Generation 0 Values \n 2: View Generation 0 Values \n 3: Run Model \n 4: Print values"))

    if option == 1:
        juveniles,adults,seniles = setGen()
    elif option == 2:
        displayGen()
    elif option == 3:
        runModel(juveniles,adults,seniles)
    elif option == 4:
        print(juveniles,adults,seniles)
    menu()


def setGen():
    #enter number of juveniles
    juveniles = int(input("How many juveniles are in the total popluation?"))
    #enter number of adults
    adults = int(input("How many Adults are in the total popluation?"))
    #enter number of seniles
    seniles = int(input("How many Seniles are in the total popluation?"))
    #enter juvenilesenile survival rates
    return(juveniles,adults,seniles)
menu()
```

how can I stop this error from happening - it doesn't seem to return anything should I use a global variable?

Comment: no one on here knows why this is happening? Really!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your variable "juveniles" is only mentioned inside of

> def menu():

and

> def setGen():

You just need to declare it as a global variable, like so:

```
global juveniles

def menu():
option = int(input("Please select an option: \n 1: Set Generation 0 Values \n 2: View Generation 0 Values \n 3: Run Model \n 4: Print values"))

if option == 1:
    juveniles,adults,seniles = setGen()
elif option == 2:
    displayGen()
elif option == 3:
    runModel(juveniles,adults,seniles)
elif option == 4:
    print(juveniles,adults,seniles)
menu()


def setGen():
#enter number of juveniles
juveniles = int(input("How many juveniles are in the total popluation?"))
#enter number of adults
adults = int(input("How many Adults are in the total popluation?"))
#enter number of seniles
seniles = int(input("How many Seniles are in the total popluation?"))
#enter juvenilesenile survival rates
return(juveniles,adults,seniles)
menu()
```